# Subset of Unicode normally used in writing?

Tags: unicode

What is the subset of Unicode characters that are normally used in writing — such as those that would be typically found in a newspaper article?

For example, in English, the characters in the range [a-zA-Z0-9], plus some punctuation characters, would be sufficient for most writing.

But I want to support languages that use characters that fall outside the ASCII range, while excluding the non-printing or decorative characters.

The objective is to restrict the user input to the application to codepoints that are legitimately used in written language. Because the user input will be saved and displayed, I do not want to allow pranksters to input text consisting entirely of things like diacritics, Unicode combining characters, Unicode flow control characters, etc.

Regrettably, I am not fluent in every single language found in Unicode. Has anyone compiled a list of all of the subset of Unicode characters that are normally used in writing?

Comment: Is your question being able to support the mostly used Unicode characters or to support all of them? Can you please explain a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Hi - I'm not at all sure I understand your question.  *Any* program or document might conceivably need to be in *any* language.  Their text may or may not be represented in "Unicode".  And even if they're "Unicode", they might be UTF-16, UTF-8, or "something else".  Q: What exactly is it you wish to know?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters Wiki is having a long list of unicodes..

Comment: PS: Please read this article.  It's a very good introduction to what Unicode is ... and *isn't*.  It will definitely help clarify some things for you: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @paulsm4: The distinction between the various binary encodings of Unicode is irrelevant for this purpose. The intent is to determine which codepoints in the entire Unicode set are used for normal writing and which are not.

Comment: Your "flowery nonsense" includes characters that might reasonably be used in written text, such as ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT NINE, THAI CHARACTER FONGMAN, and several combining characters such as COMBINING TILDE.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Good point. I've revised my question.

Comment: @Gangadhar: Please see my clarification above. The objective is to restrict the user input to the application to codepoints that are legitimately used in written language.

Comment: It sounds as though what you're trying to do is "A technical solution to a social problem"—such efforts often have unintended side-effects and are doomed to failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want to allow pranksters to input text consisting entirely of things like diacritics, Unicode combining characters

Diacritics/combining characters will be used in normal written language. So if you want to stop 'pranksters' you're going to need something more sophisticated than just a list of permitted characters. You'll have to do some sort of linguistic analysis for every language you want to permit.

I'd recommend not bothering with this, because it's going to be hard and you won't succeed anyway. Just let people write what they want.

Answer (score 3):

The official list of Unicode code points is [`UnicodeData.txt`](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt).  This is a plain text file with one line per code point; it's easily machine-readable. For example:

```
0022;QUOTATION MARK;Po;0;ON;;;;;N;;;;;
```

The third semicolon-delimited field is the abbreviated name of the "General Category".  This is explained further in [chapter 4 of the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch04.pdf), specifically in section 4.5; see the table on page 131 (page 12 of the PDF file). For example, "Lu" is uppercase letters, "Ll" is lowercase letters, Pc, Pd, Ps, *et al* are various kinds of punctuation. (The first letter of the two-letter abbreviation represents a higher-level category such as letter, digit, punctuation, etc.)

Note that some ranges of code points are not listed explicitly. For example, the range of CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) ideographs is represented as:

```
4E00;<CJK Ideograph, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
9FCC;<CJK Ideograph, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
```

I think there are other files on unicode.org that fill in these gaps.

I'm still not 100% clear on just what subset you're trying to define, but you can probably define it as a particular set of General Category values.

Comment: I have no idea what the OP is actually asking, because I don’t know what a “decorative” character is: a combining character? a symbol? punctuation? private use code points?  Nonetheless, there is an standard Unicode character property for getting at a “printable” character, and a reasonable definition for the same is given in UTS#18 Annex C, Compatibility Properties, where both a `\p{print}` and a `\p{graph}` property are explained.

Comment: Maybe the OP want's to accept legitimate names, words, form entries (first, last, street, ...) including Arabic, Chinese, Korean, Thai... while ruling out that someone decides to be called (or live in) `;DROP TABLE *` or similar :) This makes sense i.e. in the context of form submits or image metadata validation. Security or sanity, that something is valid text, not decorative garbage. At least, for this reason [Keith Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) pointer is really valuable... Thumbs up!

Comment: @Fronker: What are "legitimate" names? The solution to the [Bobby Tables problem](http://xkcd.com/327/) is to design your application so it won't try to execute user data.

Comment: Legitimate, ok well, 'potentially valid' Names are Names given to people all over the world. Including all unicode (script) languages. I know, there are easier security measures against injection attacs. Still, for sanity checking i.e tens of thousands of form submits or metadata assets, such could be a strong help. There are plenty of 丁云, but not a single ❦♞♧♨ on _this_ planet... (admittedly getting off-topic)

Comment: @Fronker: Sure, but any method that can safely handle Bobby Tables and  丁云 shouldn't have any trouble with ❦♞♧♨. It's easier, both conceptually and practically, to accept *everything* (or at least all printable characters) than to enforce arbitrary restrictions. (Hmm, is the symbol formerly used by the artist formerly known as the artist formerly known as Prince available in Unicode?)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try WGL4 (652 characters), MES-1 (335 characters) or MES-2 (1062 characters). Find these at Wikipedia.
You may wish to exclude characters ĲĳĸĿŀŉ˚―⅛⅜⅝⅞♪ from MES-1 if you want to use this set.</s>

Edit: I realize this is a bad answer. Especially the removing characters from MES-1 part was total garbage. I shouldn't have posted this. I'm ashamed of whoever upvoted this.

If anything, use Subset1 (678 characters), Subset2 (1193 characters) and Subset3 (2823 characters). https://unicodesubsets.miraheze.org/wiki/User:PiotrGrochowski